# C# and Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, command-prompt

Whenever i run a C# console app on Visual Studio, it uses the windows' default cmd instead of the Visual Studio cmd. How can i change this ?

Comment: This requirement absolutely makes no sense.

Comment: What? Can you clarify what exactly is the Visual Studio cmd?

Comment: Right click on the _Developer Command Prompt_, then `Properties`, `Target`: `%comspec% /k ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\VsDevCmd.bat""`, where `%comspec% ` is `cmd.exe`.

Comment: Why do you need your console app to be running in the visual studio command prompt? This is intended for development purposes only.